# Maven build issue, cannot resolve present artifact

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am running into the following issue with Maven. I have currently one parent project with 10 child projects (clean checkout) using Eclipse w/ m2e.

On Project->Clean I receive the following error:

```
Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml. Run Maven->Update Project or use Quick Fix for one of the child projects.
```

On running Maven->Update Project (with and without Force), as well as Quick Fix I get the following error:

```
'Updating Maven Project' has encountered a problem. Could not resolve artifact com.ema.qdsl:qdsl-jpa:jar:a-hone-jar:0.0.0
```

When I check /.m2/repository/com/ema/qdsl/qdsl-jpa/4.1.1/ there is a qdsl-jpa-4.1.1-a-hone-jar.jar present there.

What could be the issue here? Or am I misunderstanding the notation of the artifact maven cannot resolve?

Comment: It seems it looks after version 0.0.0? Maybe there is no version entered?

Comment: That was my first guess as well but there is a version tag with 4.1.1. I have an exact copy of /.m2/repository of another machine which has the exact same code and it can build. (Same pom files, etc.)

Comment: Does it work on command line?

Comment: Nope; I get the same error.

Comment: Can you show how the dependency is defined?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing the dependency version in your pom.xml